# Really minor complaint about the off-topic close menu

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

In the off-topic part of the close menu, the radio button for "this question does not appear to be about math" is annoyingly close to the link to the help center, at least for me:

[image]

Twice now I've attempted to click on the former only to click on the latter. Can something be done about this? (Again, I recognize that this is quite minor.)

Comment: I think there were previous requests for links to be disabled in close and flag dialogs on MSO. There is no reason to ever follow the links from there, disabling them would be the easiest way to solve this problem.

Comment: Relevant MSO-links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184471/delinkify-links-in-ot-close-reasons
, 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136270/can-the-links-be-disabled-in-the-vote-to-close-dialog

Answer (score 12):

What we did was, we made clicking that link open in a new window. So even if you misclick, you don't lose your context. See [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136270/can-the-links-be-disabled-in-the-vote-to-close-dialog) for details.